# react-native save button status after changing screens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have 5 buttons ["running", "riding", "reading", "coding", "Niuer"] in my app and when I click on it, the button changes its color and displays the title on screen. I am using this library: [react-native-selectmultiple-button](https://github.com/danceyoung/react-native-selectmultiple-button).

Say I clicked button "running", and "riding", these buttons will be highlighted and text will display on screen but when I change the screen to another page and come back to the previous screen button state is set back to default.

Below is my code:

```
const multipleData = ["running", "riding", "reading", "coding", "Niuer"];

export default class SimpleButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      multipleSelectedDataLimited: []
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{paddingTop:200}}>
      <Text style={styles.welcome}>
        implement the multiple-select buttons demo by SelectMultipleButton
      </Text>
      <Text style={{ color: 'blue', marginLeft: 10 }}>
      I like {_.join(this.state.multipleSelectedDataLimited, ", ")}
      </Text>
        <View
          style={{
            flexWrap: "wrap",
            flexDirection: "row",
            justifyContent: "center"
          }}
        >
          {multipleData.map(interest => (
            <SelectMultipleButton
              key={interest}
              buttonViewStyle={{
                borderRadius: 10,
                height: 40
              }}
              textStyle={{
                fontSize: 15
              }}
              highLightStyle={{
                borderColor: "gray",
                backgroundColor: "transparent",
                textColor: "gray",
                borderTintColor: 'blue',
                backgroundTintColor: 'blue',
                textTintColor: "white"
              }}
              value={interest}
              selected={this.state.multipleSelectedDataLimited.includes(
                interest
              )}
              singleTap={valueTap =>
                this._singleTapMultipleSelectedButtons_limited(interest)
              }
            />
          ))}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  _singleTapMultipleSelectedButtons_limited(interest) {
    if (this.state.multipleSelectedDataLimited.includes(interest)) {
      _.remove(this.state.multipleSelectedDataLimited, ele => {
        return ele === interest;
      });
    } else {
      if (this.state.multipleSelectedDataLimited.length < 3)
        this.state.multipleSelectedDataLimited.push(interest);
    }
    this.setState({
      multipleSelectedDataLimited: this.state.multipleSelectedDataLimited
    });
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  welcome: {
    margin: 10,
    marginTop: 30,
    color: "gray"
  }
});
```

Is there a way I could keep the status of the buttons even after changing the screen?

Any advice or comments would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could achieve this - one simple way might be to use [the `AyncStorage` API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html) to persist the state of your buttons so that it can be restored on return to this screen.

So you could use this by:

```
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native"
```

and then in `_singleTapMultipleSelectedButtons_limited(interest)` you could add the following to the end of the function:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('button_state',
     JSON.stringify(this.state.multipleSelectedDataLimited));
```

finally, you'd add this method to your component to initialise your button state from any data that was persisted:

```
componentDidMount() {
  try {
    // Fetch data from store if it exists
    AsyncStorage.getItem('button_state').then(data => {

      // If data present, try and parse it and restore button state from it
      if(data) {
        const multipleSelectedDataLimited = JSON.parse(data);
        this.setState({ multipleSelectedDataLimited })
      }          
    });
  }
  catch(err){
    console.log('Failed to load button state')
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

The best thing you can do is save your state in **Redux** and use **redux-persist** with that. You can also use **AsyncStorage**. I had similar scenario, I had to maintain state between two component navigating back and forth, I have used navigation params like this:

Screen A:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenB', {
              onPressScreenAFun: (params) => {
                this.screenAFun(params),
                ButtonState1: true // you can send multiple params
              },
            })

screenAFun = (ButtonState1) => {
 this.setState({buttonState1: ButtonState1})
}
```

Screen B:

```
    screenBFun = (params) => {
       const { onPressScreenAFun, ButtonState1 } = this.props.navigation.navigate.state.params

      onPressScreenAFun(ButtonState1)
      this.props.navigation.goBack()
    }
```