# Refresh data when navigating back react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

How do I refresh my data when navigating back? For example, if I want to edit something and then press the "Back arrow", I want to immediately see the changes.

```
    componentWillMount() {
    getData("data", (res) => {
        this.setState({ name: res.name, date: res.date});
        var date = new moment(this.state.date);
        var currentDate = new moment(); 
        var duration = moment.duration(date.diff(currentDate)).as("days");
        duration = Math.round(duration + 1).toString();
        var daysLeftPercent = Math.round([duration / 340] * 100);
        this.setState({ daysLeft: duration, daysLeftPercent: daysLeftPercent});

    }); 
}
```

Like this but I also want to run it when pressing the "back arrow" on another page that leads to this.

Comment: this is how you can access Screen A function when navigating back from screen B https://stackoverflow.com/a/52732960/7462666 you can simply call refresh when navigating back

Comment: Please read doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html. You can use `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` or `static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state)
`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a component's method from another component, you should bind it(may within props or navigation params).
And to access 'back arrow'(i think you means devıce's back button otherwise its up to you) you can use BackHandler from react native.

```
  BackHandler.addEventListener(
    "hardwareBackPress",
    this.props.onPressBackButton
  );
  ...
  onPressBackButton = () => {
    //do something
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You if you want to navigate back to a previous component and pass data to the previous component you can use () => this.props.navigation.goBack()

For example if you wanted to click a button to go back:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack(
  //do something here

  )}>    
  <Text> Go Back to previous component </Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: Can I add that to the button that's in the top left(In the header) instead of creating a new one?

Comment: If you use navigationOptions to navigate between components, by default there will be a back button on the left part of the component header

Comment: @perry So how to set goBack callback of the default Back button (if we're not using custom left header)?

Answer (score 0):

How to Make the Screen Refresh when Navigating Back in React Native----

React.useEffect(() => { const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => { Alert.alert('Refreshed'); }); return unsubscribe; }, [navigation]);

use this into useefect and before render/return

Comment: I think they're asking to refetch the data, no refresh the entire page.